# why '\0' is not pushed to stack to indicate the end of string?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm new to C, sorry if my question sounds dumb.
We know that for string like this below(from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm:

```
char greeting[] = "Hello";
```

C will append special character `\0` in the memory to indicate the end of the string as picture below shows:
[image]

So I just did an experiment to prove `\0` is in memory, below is my code:

**C code:**

```
int main()
{
   char str[] = "dd";
   printf("%s", str);
   return 0;
}
```

**assembly code:**

```
//only show relevant code
main:
   subq $24, %rsp
   movw $25700, (%rsp)  //decimal 25700 is 0x6464 where hex 64(decimal 100) is 'd' in ascii
   movb $0, 2(%rsp)
   ...
   call printf
   ...
```

so you can see that the assembly code only push "dd" to stack, what about `\0`? it doesn't get pushed to stack? then how does C know the second 'd' is the end of the string?

Comment: What about the `movb $0, 2(%rsp)`?

Comment: @tkausl so `\0` is actually 0 in memory?

Comment: @slowjams Not just in memory: `'\0' == 0` is unconditionally guaranteed to be true.

Comment: What gets pushed on the stack is the *starting address* of the string. The memory at that address contains 'd', 'd', '\0'.

Comment: '\0' is completely equivalent to 0

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker the string itself gets pushed on the stack.

Comment: @user253751 Why would a compiler do something as silly as that? `printf()` expects an address.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker because it's a local variable...?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: The starting address of the string actually doesn't need to get pushed onto the stack at all; on x86-64 it's passed to `printf` in a register.

Comment: Yes, passing the address in a register is fine as well. But it's still an address. There's no reason at all for the strings's content to be mucked with at all, local or otherwise. Strings are pointers, which are addresses.

Comment: @slowjams: I think your use of the word "push" is confusing matters.  It's true that the compiler allocates space on the stack for the array `str` and generates code to write the characters `d`, `d`, `\0` into that space.  But it doesn't happen to be using the `push` instruction to do it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It's allocating memory on the stack to hold the string, then passing the address in a register to `printf`. The 0 is there because it's pushing 0x00006464, and Intel machines are little-endian.

Comment: There's a missed optimization here - if OP had declared `str` as `char *` instead of `char []`, the string would have gone in the program's read-only data section and at runtime only its address would have had to be loaded.  The compiler _could_ be taught to recognize that in this case there is no need for `str` to be a writable local variable, and emit the same code it would have for `char *`.

Comment: The problem contains some misunderstanding and confusion. But exactly because of that I consider it interesting and helpful. Somebody please make an answer. I would like to avoid this being closed as pure thinko. slowjams You can create your own answer from what you learned in the comments and give credit to the helpful comment-authors.

Comment: @Rubberbee what's the confusion of my question? I think I got the answer from tkausl, you can see the third instruction push 0 to stack, and 0 means null in ASCII, which is end of string I think, can anybody confirm that ASCII 0 (null) is the same as \0 in C?

Comment: Please create an answer from that informatin. It is just a better to have a Q/A pair than having a Q/hiddencommentinformation pair.